# bluetooth low energy; ble security

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on bluetooth low energy product which has no I/O capabilities. Wondering how we can make pair two products secure with out exchanging the key?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to tell us more about your security goals. You mentioned that you can't exchange the key out in the open, and that's a start, but how determined do you actually expect an attacker to be? Is this a humidity sensor or a pacemaker for the President?

You also need to describe the device ecosystem. Is this device a Central or a Peripheral? Are you creating your own mobile app? Are you targeting iOS and Android? UWP?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible approaches:

1) Configure your product to generate a fixed key, if possible, and include the key value in the user guide for your product.
2) Use the "JustWorks" pairing method.  This uses the Numeric Comparison protocol but the user is never shown a number.  From the Bluetooth standard (V4.2): "The JustWorks association model provides the same protection as the Numeric Comparison association model against passive eavesdropping but offers no protection against the MITM (man-in-the-middle) attack."

Consult the documentation for your radio or contact the radio supplier for information on how to implement either of these methods.

Comment: OOB pairing is also possible, where the key is provided on a different (non-Bluetooth) channel. This is similar to your option 1), but it is defined in V4.2 as well.